# Wget ends at ampersand(&) and skips eveything after that

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, wget

Wget skips everything after ampersand (`&`). I tried escaping &, but it is not working

Code:

```
import threading
import urllib.request
import os
import re
import time
import json
import sys

def take():
    a = ["https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-games-action/id7001?mt=8&letter=A","https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-games-action/id7001?mt=8&letter=B"]
    for url_file in a:
        url_file = re.sub(r'\&','\&',url_file)
        data = os.popen('wget -qO- %s'% url_file).read()
        if re.search(r'(?mis)paginate\-more\">next',data):
            print ("hi")

take()
```

This should print `"hi"`

But since Wget skips everything after `&`, it is throwing blank output.

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that `&` has a special meaning in the shell (and you are calling a shell via `popen`): that is to background the job on the left-hand side of the ampersand.

To circumvent this, you have to escape the special characters, or use quotes around the URL:

```
 data = os.popen('wget -qO- "%s"' % url_file).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me as it is. I am using Python 2.6.x on Linux.

The output is

```
hi
hi
```

I see that you have escaped '&' in your source.