# wget is not working with special parameter

Tags: shell, command-line, parameters, wget

I am trying to download a file from this link with wget.

`https://sfirmware.com/downloads/downloader.php?fileid=257457&hash=458cd40aa7824c3d25fe096c0b01d4b7`

I am aware that `&` is a special character in shell environment.

So far i've tried double quote,single quote ,putting %26 replacing '&' (as per some suggestion) but the solution doesn't seem to work with this error-

```
Hash not exist in db!<a href="https://sfirmware.com/">Back to Home Page</a>
```

It seems the hash number from the link is ignoring while requesting.

How do I modify the code to download this file with wget?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wget ends at ampersand(&) and skips eveything after that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400021/wget-ends-at-ampersand-and-skips-eveything-after-that)

Comment: Or closely related: [How to include an '&' character in a bash curl statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13339469/3266847)

Comment: No. As I already mentioned. I tried those before asking questioning here

Comment: Maybe the file is indeed missing?

Comment: No. You can go to the link with browser and the file should be downloading

Comment: I get a message that the file doesn't exist when I do that.

Comment: Link is updating after a while. Is there any solution to wget this file? link is valid

Comment: I can't tell you anything other than single quoting the whole URL works for me.